# How can I add shapes to an SVG using javascript?

Tags: javascript, svg

Anything I try to add with javascript doesn't show up. Here is the html.

```
<svg width="100" height="100" id="test">
    <rect width="10" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);">
</svg>
```

The rectangle shows up fine. Here is the javascript:

```
var b = document.createElement('rect');
b.setAttribute('width', 100);
b.setAttribute('height', 100);
b.setAttribute('style', 'fill:rgb(0,0,255);');
document.getElementById('test').appendChild(b);
```

Inspect shows this:

```
<svg width="100" height="100" id="test">
    <rect width="10" height="10" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);">
    <rect width="100" height="100" style="fill:rgb(0,0,255);">
</svg>
```

But `b` doesn't show up. Does the svg have to be updated or something?

Note: I would like to avoid external libraries like jQuery and keep this a simple as possible.

Comment: Side-note: jQuery does not generally support SVG, so don't use that anyway.

Comment: You need to use `createElementNS( svgNS, 'rect' )`, where `svgNS` is the SVG namespace: `"http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"`.

Comment: @Phrogz is there a way to use that namespace without having to link to it? Like download some file?

Comment: you're not linking to it by using it there

Comment: @billyhafiz Go read the related pages. See how they just use the string directly (or, if you have the namespace on your `<svg>` element, by just referencing the attribute.

Comment: Will that work without an internet connection?

Comment: @billyhafiz Yes. It is just a string. It looks like a URL (it is a URL), but no resources are requested from that URL. It is just a special, unique identifier.